# borkin button without screen

Tags: pi-3

I have installed a jack button to turn on and off my raspberry pi 3 following the method described in the youtbue video
[The Borkin Button Easy Raspberry Pi Power Butto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A08IrJ3ECuA).

This allows to create a shutdown and boot up switch taking advantage of the 3.55mm av(audio video) jack.

For this to work the GPIO PIN 5 needs to be connected with a wire to the jack
[image]

Then the script below manage starting/shutting down the device.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
import subprocess

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)  

# use the same pin that is used for the reset button (one button to rule them all!)
GPIO.setup(5, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_UP)  

oldButtonState1 = True

while True:
        #grab the current button state
        buttonState1 = GPIO.input(5)

    # check to see if button has been pushed
    if buttonState1 != oldButtonState1 and buttonState1 == False:
      subprocess.call("shutdown -h now", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
      oldButtonState1 = buttonState1

       time.sleep(.1)
```

It does work fine when the raspi is connected to a screen. However when not connected to a screen the button doesn't work.

Anyone can shed some light on what the issue could be?

Comment: Keep in mind most people are unlikely to bother watching a youtube video for you, so  you may want to actually explain what you have done.

Comment: just a hunch ... try launching shutdown without the extra arguments to `subprocess.call()` like so `subprocess.call("shutdown -h now")`

Answer (score 0):

If you use certain displays that use all GPIO pins, this will not work..
Using Pimoroni HyperPixel 4"

Running script to watch Pin5, makes LCD go black

Comment: Is this meant to answer the question or comment on something else?